# libGL does exists, but linker can't find it - Qt 4.8.7, CentOS 7.5

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, centos7, nvidia

I have `CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804` with `Qt 4.8.7` installed from `base repo`. I installed `NVidia driver version 390.59 release date 2018.5.16`.
I have `libGL-mesa` and `libGL-mesa-devel` **INSTALLED** also.
My graphics card Quadro K4000M is doing just fine - for example, `glxgears` 60fps, Qt Demos (OpenGL) work.

But when I am trying to compile the `chip` example, I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libGL.so when searching for -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [chip] Error 1
```

Here is the `ls` command output:

```
[user@centos-7 ~]$ ls -h /usr/lib64/ | grep "libGL"
libGLdispatch.so.0
libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.390.59
libGLESv1_CM.so
libGLESv1_CM.so.1
libGLESv1_CM.so.1.2.0
libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
libGLESv2_nvidia.so.390.59
libGLESv2.so
libGLESv2.so.2
libGLESv2.so.2.1.0
libGL.la
libGL.so
libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1.7.0
libGLU.so
libGLU.so.1
libGLU.so.1.3.1
libGLX_indirect.so.0
libGLX_nvidia.so.0
libGLX_nvidia.so.390.59
libGLX.so
libGLX.so.0
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Have a look at this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364944/ld-cannot-find-lgl-on-centos-7

Comment: Stock Qt is built against mesa drivers. If you want it to use other drivers, you may have to build it yourself.

Comment: @dtech
Demo apps, provided with Qt in binary form, works fine - I mean OpenGL is supported. And they are using `/usr/lib64/libGL.so` - the lib, that `ld` can't find somehow while linking the same example.
If demos work using NVIDIA drivers installed, why I can't link the same example?

Comment: Well, I wish I could help you with that, but I don't have any ideas. I will reopen your question, maybe someone else will help. You might want to improve the title to a more descriptive form, this way it may not get that much attention.

Comment: @dtech
I have just uninstalled NVIDIA driver and building **chip** project now goes without any errors ... :-/
Screen resolution is ugly, but OpenGL is supported as it was when NVIDIA driver was installed - I mean Qt demos and examples.

Comment: Maybe there is some way to specify a particular driver to be used by Qt, like there is one for the windows platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is solved - I install NVIDIA the **latest** driver (`version: 390.67 release Date: 2018.6.5`) in this way: http://www.advancedclustering.com/act_kb/installing-nvidia-drivers-rhel-centos-7/.